# Ruby on rails. Pay to post articles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, paypal

I am have been using rails for about a week now and have created a website/app which for simplicity's sake we can call a job board. Users can create listings which other users can then apply for. Everything is working as desired. The next thing that I want to set up is the ability to charge users to create the listings. 
  After extensive searching, I can't find any tutorials that explain this process, just the typical cart and checkout for selling physical products.

I have been pondering solutions but I wanted to consult here for pro advice.
For the payment process (at least for now) I will most likely use active merchant and Paypal as I am based in Europe.

My current doubts are with setting up the modeling.

Would it be better to create a new model eg. 'credits', have users purchase 'credits', then run a variable when trying to create a 'job', eg.  if_user_has_credits post the job else link to buy_credits_path, or is there a  more direct way of achieving this through the already functional user and jobs models?

Any advice on setting up this functionality would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Yes, your line of thought sounds good. That's how I would do it (user buys credits, then spends them on site activities)

Comment: I think your line of thought makes sense, as long as you can get the payments set up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try to create a credit system, so users just have to purchase credits and you can just drive the user to purchase credits in case they do not have enough for create a listing:

- Simple one: Store the user' credit as balance field in the database, and all actions ("add", "deduct") are logged but not used to compute the latest balance. The balance-based way gives you fast access to the current amount
- History based: Don't store the balance in database. The balance is computed by looking at the history of transactions, e.g. ("add", "deduct"). The history-based way gives you auditing. The history table should store the transaction, a timestamp, the balance before the transaction happened, and ideally a way to track the funds' source/destination.

You can use both. See the [Ruby toolbox for bookeeping](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=bookkeeping) and [Plutus](https://github.com/mbulat/plutus)

I recommend also using logging, and ideally read about secure log verification and provable timestamp chaining.

For logging details see [techniques for ensuring verifiability of event log files](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/4320/techniques-for-ensuring-verifiability-of-event-log-files)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, although I am in way over my head here. I am going to start by creating a new 'token' model, and see if I can get it working without payment. If I am successful I'll implement payment and logging for the 'tokens'.